# How to select last value insert in column ( like function LAST() for OracleDB)

Tags: postgresql

I'm actually sutend and I'm setting up DB PostgreSQL for my AirsoftShop and some request on it. I need to find similar function as SELECT LAST(xx) FROM yy usable on SQL server and OracleDB i think. For return the last insert values in the column target by LAST().

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE munition.suivi_ammo (
    type_ammo integer NOT NULL,
    calibre integer NOT NULL,
    event integer NOT NULL,
    date_event date NOT NULL,
    entrance integer NOT NULL,
    exit integer NOT NULL,
    inventory integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (calibre) REFERENCES munition.index(numero),
    FOREIGN KEY (event) REFERENCES munition.index(numero),
    FOREIGN KEY (type_ammo) REFERENCES munition.index(numero)
);
```

and index for definition by number id :

```
CREATE TABLE munition.index (
    numero integer NOT NULL,
    definition text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (numero) 
);
```

I want to select the last inventory insert in the table and calculate the current inventory according to the inflow and outflow made after my inventory

It's works when i do this type of request with specific date to be sure to only have the last one inventory, but I do not want to have to do it

```
SELECT index.definition,
Sum(suivi_ammo.inventory) + Sum(suivi_ammo.entrance) - Sum(suivi_ammo.exit) AS Stock
FROM munition.suivi_ammo
INNER JOIN munition.index ON suivi_ammo.type_ammo = index.numero
WHERE date_event < '03/05/2019' AND date_event >= '2019-04-10'
GROUP BY index.definition;
```

I also tried to used last_value() window function but doesn't work.
Thx !

Comment: It is not clear from your question, but maybe you are looking for the current value of a sequence (which can be found with the `currval()` function). But for that you'd need to define a `DEFAULT` value for a column that uses a sequence.

Comment: Oh sorry if it wasn’t clear, but you understood the problem visibly, I’ll try this, I hadn’t thought about it, it seems to me to be a good solution, thaks a lot !:)